# WCF Service WSDL Link with domain name

Tags: wcf, iis, wsdl

When i publish my WCF 4.0 service to server, the domain name is always converted to IP value in wsdl address. What i mean is; i want the wsdl link to be
http://www.mydomainaddress/svc/service1.svc?wsdl, instead of http://myipaddress/svc/service1.svc?wsdl

Comment: What do you mean that it's "converted"? Which WSDL Link are you referring to?

Comment: WSDL link always appears with the ip value, like "http://121.12.11.33/svc/service1.svc?wsdl", not domain name..

Comment: What is this "WSDL Link" that you're referring to?

Comment: Oh, sorry.It is the one you see after calling service from a browser, the one on the "you have created a service" page.

Comment: Check your bindings in IIS. That part of the URL comes from IIS. If the application in IIS is set up to bind via the IP address, then that's what you'll get in the help page and in the WSDL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>` tag to the `serviceBehaviors` element in the config so the landing page will show the host header you typed into your browser, rather than the machine name/ip.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816894.aspx for more.

Comment: Question states WCF 4.0, so this answer is valid. Please note that this won't work in prior versions of WCF.